# Como montar par de array key vaue para inserir na tabela?

Tags: php, mysql, array, pdo

```
$key = "id,name";
$val = "'$lastid','$autor'";
...
if ($email){
   $key .= ",email";
   $val .= ",'$email'";
}
...
$keys = \explode(',', $key);
$vals = \explode(',', $val);
$arr  = array_combine($keys,array_fill(0,count($keys),$vals));
....
//O array montado fica assim:
// INSERT INTO autores (id, name, email) VALUES (:id, :name, :email)

$insok = $pdo->insert($arr);
if (!$insok) {
    $error = "Erro ao inserir dados<br>".print_r($conn->errorInfo());
}

echo $error; // mostra o seguinte resultado

//array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }
```

Gostaria de saber como resolver esse erro:

Answer (score 0):

É só simplificar, não precisa daquele `array_fill()` basta chamar o `array_combine()` com `$keys` e `$vals`. Se for utilizar prepared statements não inclua aspas simples no valores.

Troque:

```
$arr  = array_combine($keys,array_fill(0,count($keys),$vals));
```

Por:

```
$arr  = array_combine($keys, $vals);
```

Seu array ficará dessa forma:

```
Array
(
    [id] => '10'
    [name] => 'fulano'
)
```

Comment: Olá, muito obrigado pela rápida resposta. O problema realmente estava nas aspas simples. O correto é:

$key = "id, name";
$val = $id. "," .$cauthor;

E também simplifiquei o array_combine() como vc falou.

Funcionou ok.

Um abraço.

Comment: @user1818765 com `array_fill()` fica assim: `Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => '10'
            [1] => 'fulano'
        )

    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => '10'
            [1] => 'fulano'
        )

)`